# Event handler always called with the same value in foreach loop

Tags: c#, user-interface, lambda, callback

I want to bind a set of callback functions to GUI elements in C#, each calling the same processing function with a different argument.

The spelled-out way

```
# Assign element #1 to widget

widget.Click += () => {ProcessClick(1) ;} ;

# Assign element #2 to widget

widget.Click += () => {ProcessClick(2) ;} ;

...
```

seems redundant. However, a naive loop of

```
Widget widget ;

foreach (int i in new List<int>() {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} )
{
    # Assign element i to widget

    widget.Click += () => {ProcessClick(i) ;} ;
}
```

will not work, as the loop will have expired once any callback is being called, resulting in a call of `ProcessClick(9)` for each widget.

I feel there should be a simple solution for this, but I'm stuck.

How can I bind callback functions to the GUI elements each calling a function with a different argument without spelling them all out?

Comment: Lots of useful stuff from Eric Lippert on this subject http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/closures/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`i` is captured by your delegate during the loop. You'll need to copy its value to a local variable in your loops to make it work:

```
Widget widget ;

foreach (int i in new List<int>() { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 } )
{
    # Assign element i to widget

    int index = i;
    widget.Click += () => {ProcessClick(index) ;} ;
}
```

More info on variables capture can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) and on [Eric Lipper's blog](http://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/). On the latter you'll also find info about the breaking changes the C# team made in C# 5 for which the variable is logically inside the loop (as noted by DavidG).

Comment: Worth noting that this was changed in C# version 5, now closures will close over a fresh copy of the variable each time.

Comment: The fact that actually escaped me was that `int index` creates a *different* instance of `index` that can be referenced by each lambda function respectively. Thanks!

Comment: @fbmd As DavidG wrote, the loop variable in C# 5 is internal to the loop block and is no longer captured as explained by Eric Lippert here: http://ericlippert.com/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-two/