# How can I manage an process that using same variable in all tasks

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm creating 10 tasks and every task creates a number with increment. Then i enqueue to **ConcurrentQueue** As a result `i` there are 10 numbers in the queue but every numbers value is 10.

How can I set every numbers in queue have different value (0 to 9). Also the TaskTest() method should complete in less than 10 second.

```
public async void TaskTest()
{
    ConcurrentQueue<int> queue;
    queue = await GetNumbers();
}
```

```
private async Task<ConcurrentQueue<int>> GetNumbers()
{
    ConcurrentQueue<int> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    int i = 0;
    while (i<10)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var number = CreateNumber(i);
            queue.Enqueue(number);
        }));
        Interlocked.Increment(ref i);
    }
    
    foreach (var t in tasks)
    {
        await t;
    }
    return queue;
}
```

```
private int CreateNumber(int i)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return i;
}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: You should be careful about accidentally modifying captured variables like `i` after starting the thread, because the `i` is shared. Here is the solution to your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/34319356/2946329

Comment: You will need to capture `i` for each task. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25973952/1997232).

Comment: Can't find good duplicate, the best I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3168375/1997232).

Comment: You shouldn't use `Task.Factory.StartNew`, use [`Task.Run`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38423507/542251). I'd also recommend you use [`Task.Delay`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20084603/542251) not `Thread.Sleep` as this can then unblock the thread

Comment: Solved. Thanks for your answer @SalahAkbari. Also I consider your answer Fildor

Comment: and use [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netcore-3.1) not your `for` loop. Basically throw all this away and start again using proper up to date TPL

Comment: I'd *also* mention that that duplciate answer is 5 years old and is also out of date. In 2020 you should never have to manipulate the `Thread` directly. Pretty much always use the `Task` abstraction as it gives you asynchronicity

Comment: How to write basically this code with your recommended way? @Liam. I don't have more information about TPL

Comment: They closed the question just as I wanted to post answer - you can create a situation where a new variable will be captured by each of the created Task items (threads), like this:while (i < 10){int temp = i;tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>... - it give numbers as you expected and finishes in <10 sec

Comment: The return value of `Interlocked.Increment` is important in your case. It is the only way to know the current value of `i` with thread-safety: `int localIndex = Interlocked.Increment(ref i);`

Comment: Are the queued values supposed to be consumed while those tasks are queueing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding `while (i<10)`, if you know the number iterations up front, you should really be using a `for` loop rather than a `while`.

Using a `for` loop or `Enumerable.Range` you don't need to worry about manipulating `i` in a thread safe way:

```
private async Task<ConcurrentQueue<int>> GetNumbers()
{
    ConcurrentQueue<int> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();

    Task EnqueOnThreadPoolAsync(int i) => Task.Run(() => queue.Enqueue(CreateNumber(i)));

    await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(EnqueOnThreadPoolAsync));

    return queue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Barclay. It looks like better solution for my problem.