# Why are some of task are not being executed?

Tags: c#, task

I have  this Code below that runs in a Task. I want my program to more responsive but when I try to run the code below. Some of the task are successfully completed.

```
   private async void SaveRecordToDB()
    {
        List<Task> listOfTask = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
        {
            listOfTask.Add(Task.Run(() => IterateRowsSaving(i)));

        }

        await Task.WhenAll(listOfTask);
    }

    private bool IterateRowsSaving(int index)
    {
        bool Success = true;
        //Save to Database
        //Assuming that every iteration has a long operation running
        return Success;
    }
```

What could have been that I have done wrong?

Comment: Likely to be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973916/event-handler-always-called-with-the-same-value-in-foreach-loop) in that `index` is always the same value when received by `IterateRowsSaving` (should always be 16). Can you confirm that this is the issue you're seeing?

Comment: Not really sir, but I did one time notice that the IterateRowsSaving was always 16. But now what I am getting is some of the task were successfully executed (like 3-6 records) and other were not. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: and should be the 16 records to be processed

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `index` isn't (almost) always 16? I can reliably reproduce that problem with your code. See here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vyZ117

Comment: But if I edit your code as in the other question I linked, you can see that it doesn't do that anymore and now propagates the correct values: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8dnT8Y

Comment: Side note: `async void` is evil, try `async Task` instead. Please, note, that `async void` provides *fire and forget* policy

Comment: Sir @Llama , I was testing my code and that 1 piece of line of code that I did not have was the culprit. And I didn't Expect that.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, you say that `IterateRowsSaving` writes to the database. Your database code probably has async methods, which means you could make `IterateRowsSaving` async, and then not have to run each call to `IterateRowsSaving` in a new `Task`, you could simply do something like `listOfTask.Add(IterateRowsSaving(idx));` in that case.

Comment: @Llama I'm gonna try that. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two potential problems here:

1. `async void` which means *fire and forget* policy; better use `async Task`
2. You use loop variable `i` within tasks. Note, that `i == 15` after all the tasks
   started.

```
    //DONE: async Task instead of async void 
    private async Task SaveRecordToDB()
    {
        List<Task> listOfTask = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
        {
            // Each task should depend on its own local variable
            int index = i;

            listOfTask.Add(Task.Run(() => IterateRowsSaving(index)));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(listOfTask);
    }
```